# How to build a few instance of @nuxtjs/axios

Tags: axios, nuxt.js

How to build a few instances of `@nuxtjs/axios` in the Nuxt project and apply throughout the project and store.

Can the built-in instance use this pointer?

Answer (score 0):

Your will needed configure a multiples axios instances, and use this instances to get/post your requests.

```
import axios from 'axios'

    const api1 = axios.create({
      baseURL: 'https://some-domain.com/api1/',
      timeout: 1000,
      headers: {'X-Custom-Header': 'foobar'}
    })

    const api2 = axios.create({
      baseURL: 'https://some-domain.com/api2/',
      timeout: 1000,
      headers: {'X-Custom-Header': 'bar'}
    })
```

so, what you need to do, is use your instance to make your requests, somethink like this:

```
api1.post('auth/recovery', payload)
ap2.post('auth/signin', payload)
```